# Ionic inject firebase into factory while keeping controller and services in different files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I'm having trouble setting up a firebase factory that can be used in my controllers. Current my code looks like this:

**index.html**

```
...
<!-- implementing firebase -->
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
...
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', 
['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { ....
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('app.services', ['firebase'])

.factory('itemsFactory', function($firebaseArray) {
  var ItemsRef = new Firebase("https://].firebaseio.com/items");
  return $firebaseArray(ItemsRef);
})

.service('BlankService', [function(){

}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('itemCtrl', function($scope, 'itemsFactory') {
  $scope.items = itemsFactory;

  $scope.saveItem = function(){
                            $scope.items.$add({
                              "name": "Frank",
                              "lastname": "Sinatra"
                            });
                        };
});
```

But there seems to be some trouble for the controller to recognize the `itemsFactory`. I tried to move the `app.servies` before the `app.controllers` but that's the not the problem.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is **itemsFactory** should not have quotes in declaration in controllers.js

You have another typo in your controller.

Instead of

```
  $scope.saveItem() = function(){
```

It should be

```
  $scope.saveItem = function(){
```

You declare the function so don't use brackets.

You have here a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dafobixuqu/edit?html,console,output) with working example.

Comment: Thank you! It is so easy to make typos in this framework. I tried to remove the quotes and (), but I'm still getting an error: `[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: you just have to change this line: `angular.module('app.controllers')`
 to this one: `angular.module('app.controllers', [])`

Comment: OMG.. such simple mistake.. I probably deleted the [ ] when I tried to add `firebase` into the controller to see if that would help. Thank you so much!